# Filtering inactivated rows in Spark using Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I am very new to Spark and Scala programming and I have a problem that I hope some smart people can help me to solve.
I have a table named users with 4 columns: status, user_id, name, date

Rows are:

```
status  user_id name    date
active      1   Peter   2020-01-01
active      2   John    2020-01-01
active      3   Alex    2020-01-01
inactive    1   Peter   2020-02-01
inactive    2   John    2020-01-01
```

I need to select only active users. Two users were inactivated. Only one was inactivated for the same date.

What I aim is to filter rows with inactive status(this I can) and to filter inactivated users when inactivation row matches columns with active row. Peter was inactivated for different date and he is not filtered. Desired result would be:

```
1 Peter 2020-01-01
3 Alex 2020-01-01
```

rows with inactive status filtered. John is inactivated, so his row is filtered too.

The closest I come is to filter users that has inactive status:

```
val users = spark.table("db.users")
      .filter(col("status").not Equal("Inactive"))
      .select("user_id", "name", "date")
```

Any ideas or suggestions how to solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: More occurrences for the same date? For same user that is?

Comment: I am pretty sure, there isn't a space between `not` and `Equal`. `notEqual` is the function. Also in the data you provided `inactive` isn't came case, in the code it is. Please fix the typos first so we can understand if there is an actual underlying problem

Comment: Yes, could be more, but to simplify this let's assume rows are distinct.

Comment: I was  not allowed to enter notEqual in subumit form. There is no isssue with the code I gave as example it's just not complete.

Answer (score 1):

Check the inactive first with group by for each user and date, and join this result into the original df.

```
val df2 = df.groupBy('user_id, 'date).agg(max('status).as("status"))
  .filter("status = 'inactive'")
  .withColumnRenamed("status", "inactive")

df.join(df2, Seq("user_id", "date"), "left")
  .filter('inactive.isNull)
  .select(df.columns.head, df.columns.tail: _*)
  .show()

+------+-------+-----+----------+
|status|user_id| name|      date|
+------+-------+-----+----------+
|active|      1|Peter|2020-01-01|
|active|      3| Alex|2020-01-01|
+------+-------+-----+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you! Solution is great. Will upvote once I reach 15 reputation.